# Имеет ли значение порядок объектов в параметре LIST процедуры DBMS_MVIEW.REFRESH?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c, stored-procedures

```
dbms_mview.REFRESH(
    LIST=>'MV_CREATIVES_MIX_WITH_NAME_DCO,MV_CREATIVES_STATISTICS_MIX_DCO,
           MV_AUTOCHECKER_UPD,MV_AUTOLINKING_DCO'
           /*, atomic_refresh => false, out_of_place => true*/);
```

В параметре `LIST` объекты:

```
MV_CREATIVES_MIX_WITH_NAME_DCO,MV_CREATIVES_STATISTICS_MIX_DCO
```

являются источниками данных для объектов:

```
MV_AUTOCHECKER_UPD,MV_AUTOLINKING_DCO
```

В данном случае, выполнются ли обновление объектов в заданном порядке?

Или, чтобы соблюсти порядок выполнения, следует выполнить обновление источников данных в отдельном JOB?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В документации [DBMS_MVIEW.REFRESH](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/arpls/DBMS_MVIEW.html#GUID-DD332F65-A5BC-4DE6-814E-EAE2E0275F3D) порядок выполнения обновлений в листе материализованных представлений не указан, т.е на него не стоит полагаться.

В MOS документе [Doc ID 1452382.1](https://support.oracle.com/knowledge/Oracle%20Database%20Products/1452382_1.html) сказано:

> In 10g and above versions, Oracle does not refresh the MVIEWs in sequence as specified in the "LIST" parameter in the DBMS_SNAPSHOT.REFRESH / DBMS_MVIEW.REFRESH procedure. MVIEWs are sorted and refreshed in alphabetical order from 10g onwards. Whereas in 9i, it refreshes the MVIEWs as specified in LIST parameter; there is no sorting by MVIEW name in 9i.

До верии 9i включительно, обновления выполнялись действительно в порядке, указанном в параметре `LIST`, а начиная с 10g обновления материализованных представлений выполняются в алфавитном порядке.